# passing data from php simple dom parser to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this simple script :

```
<?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

$content = file_get_html('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myst');
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is find a way to send this to a jquery script ....would I need to do a $.ajax GET in jquery? What would I need to add in this script.

I start my jquery code with document.ready....would this need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['getcontent'])){
    include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
    echo file_get_html('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myst');
}
?>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get("content.php",{"getcontent":"true"},function(data){
    // data is content from php-script
    // do something with it
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to render the html though. I want to pass the $content variable to another jquery file.

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you want to do?

Comment: I have another file....called processing.js.....i want to pass the $content variable (the DOM from the url)..to this file

Comment: Ok, maybe I am completely wrong but you can't pass `$content` to a jquery file. Your html code is loaded with some scripts using jquery and is static. It doesn`t have the ability to receive request vars like in php with `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Executing any other php script by the user will result in loading an new page, so your jquery code is gone. Why don`t you use the code above to request `$content` from the php script at the point you need it in jquery?